# What is the Crimson King's nickname, and why is he called that?

Tags: the-dark-tower, stephen-king

Simple question that I can't seem to easily find an answer to...

In the last book of the series (The Dark Tower), the Crimson King is called 'Los' by, I believe, Dandelo.

However, I cannot seem to remember why he is called this....

Comment: His nickname is indeed "Los", but I too cannot remember why he is called that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've read the books in another language than the original ones and didn't remember this.
I then checked in my books (in french) and it's also Los'.

As I have the original version in ebook format, I was able to search through the whole seventh book.  The first time *Los'* is used is in Part IV, chapter III: The Castle of the Crimson King.
The first occurrence I can find is when Roland, Susannah and Oy meet Feemalo, Fumalo and Fimalo.

> "Since the names we give ourself would be unpronounceable to you [...] you may as well use those Los' used. Him being the one you call the Crimson King."

Then they use the term Los' several time without giving a meaning to it (at least I didn't find it).
For example:

> "This man is as crazy as Los' the Red" Fumalo said, not without respect.

The only other person using this term is Rando Thoughtful, when caught by Mordred.

> "Mordred, son of Los'," he said, trying a smile. "Hile to you, King that will be!"

In this last book, I find the term *Los'* 10 times. 9 times used by F(ee/u/i)malo and once by Rando.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Dark_Tower_characters#The_Crimson_King) about Dark Tower characters states:

> The Crimson King is known by a number of names, including Los' the Red, Ram Aballah, The Aballah, The Kingfish, The Red King, The Lord of Spiders, and The Lord of Discordia.

I don't have yet the possibility to look in the Concordance book but I may soon. I'll check this and come back if there are any details in it.

Comment: wow, great answer....i totally had forgotton about fee/fu/fimalo.